# Geo Fencing Identifier

Tags: iphone, ios6, geofencing

How to specify the entire country as a region in region identifier.Wether it will accept the

```
identifier as :@"Uk"
```

here the code to reo identifier.How can i specify England or UK.Please help me to sort out

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location2D = mapView.region.center; 
CLRegion *regionForMonitoring = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:location2D radius:1 identifier:@"RegionIdentifier"];
[[Utils getLocationManager] startMonitoringForRegion:regionForMonitoring];
```

Answer (score 0):

CLRegions are totally unsuitable for this purpose.

First of all, the radius specified is the distance in meters that the region covers - so in your case you are asking the system to monitor a region at a specific lat/long with a radius of 1 meter!

Also, system regions have a maximum number of regions that can be monitored (around 10 or so), and a maximum radius that can be used of around 400 meters after which the region will not work.

You really need to read the "Monitoring Shape Based Regions" section of this Apple document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

There are two other possible approaches to what you are trying to do:

1) Use Significant Location Updates, and test on each update if you are in an area with a shape you specify.

2) Use CoreTelephony to look up the cell carrier your device is on and see if the carrier number matches one in the country of interest.  Of course, this will not work on some iPads or other iOS devices with no cell connection.

Neither of those approaches will be exact around the edges, but will also not consume nearly as much battery life as using the GPS.